# how to implement Delta-V (add Versioning Extensions to WebDAV )?

Tags: linux, apache, webdav

I have read that Delta-V adds  Versioning Extensions to WebDAV but I don't find how to configure my ubuntu server to implement this extentions . this is my webdav configuration and it works fine :

```
<Directory /webdav>
    Options Indexes MultiViews  FollowSymlinks
    DAV On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "webdav"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/webdav.password
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Comment: It's not supported by apache. You could run the svn server via apache. SVN implements parts of deltav.

Comment: thank you for answering, ok I'll see that . have you seen any good tutorial for this ?

Comment: Try a search engine.